# Getting relationship after user clicks

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4, relationships

Confusing huh? the title. Yes i know, but did now know how to better describe it.

I have the following:
- 9 objectives
- each objective has 3 packages
- each package has 1 packageinfo // irrelevant for this question.

```
// Relations
- Objective->hasMany('Package');
- Package->belongsToMany('Objective');
```

On a page of my webite i display all (9) objectives.
When a user clicks on a objective, i would like the related packages to show up. But it is really unclear to me how to do this (client-side)..

I tried:

```
@foreach($objectives as $objective)
    <div class="col-4">
        <span class="{{$objective->icon}}"></span>
        {{$objective->naam}}
    </div>
    @foreach($objective->packages() as $package)
        <div style="">
            {{$package->title}}
            {{$package->information}}
            {{$package->link}}
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

this neither shows the related packages nor give me an error. Besides that. Is it even correct what i am doing?

I also tried to get the packages with jquery, but this didn't work..
My question... How can i best do the above? (packages should be hidden until the user clicks on a objective, without any page change or whatsoever)

----------------- EDIT

Ignore above code please.

I had the following code:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.objective').on('click',function(){

        var objective = $(this).data('titel');
        document.getElementById('objective').value = $(this).data('title');

        // this doesnt work i know, but its here to explain the stuff beneath this.
        $id = document.getElementById('objective').value;

        // code which gets the id of hidden input and finds all packages related to this objective id.
        // i.e. Package::with('objectives')->where('id','=', $id)->get();
        // save it as $packages. Which will fill the second foreach

    });



});

</script>

<div class="col-12">
    <input type="hidden" name="objective" id="objective" />
    @foreach($objectives as $objective)
        <div class="col-4 objective" data-title="{{$objective->id}}">
            <span class="{{$objective->icon}}"></span>
            {{$objective->name}}
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>

// the two have to be seperate from eachother in order to succesfully show related packages.
<div class="col-12">
    @foreach($packages as $package)
        <div>
            {{$package->title}}
            <?php $information = explode(',',$package->information); ?>
            @foreach($information as $info)
                {{$info}}<br />
            @endforeach
            {{$package->link}}
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: I don't really know PHP but does this not show a div with the Objective and then 3 Package divs?

Comment: You would show/hide client-side divs via javascript... but I see no javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. You can do a self-posting PHP page, or modify `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` with JavaScript on the click of an element with the `onClick` HTML attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For the PHP/Laravel side of things, change your `@foreach` statement to remove the `()` after `packages`:

```
@foreach($objective->packages as $package)
```

(This assumes that your `hasMany` relation is called `packages`...double-check that is the case in your Objective model.)

---

So your controller would gather all the Objectives, and their related Packages:

```
$objectives = Objective::with('packages')->get();
```

...and pass the whole `$objectives` result to the view. Now, in the view, you have all the Objectives and Packages, and don't need to dynamically retrieve them using javascript or ID matching.

---

For the responding-to-click side of things, as others have said, you need to toggle show/hide using javascript as a response to `onClick`.

---

If you want your list of Packages to be separate from where your Objectives are displayed, i.e:

```
---
Package 1
Package 2
Package 3
...
---
Objectives (of the chosen package above)
---
```

...then just separate your loops in your layout, and show/hide the appropriate `<div>` based on the id of the chosen Package (which you can store in a `data` attribute, rather than an hidden input field).

```
<div id="objectives">
    @foreach($objectives as $objective)
        <div class="objective" data-objective-id="{{$objective->id}}">
            {{$objective->naam}}
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>

<div id="packages">
    @foreach($objectives as $objective)
        <div id="{{$objective->id}}" class="hide">
            @foreach($packages as $package)
                <div>
                    {{$package->title}}
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Your jQuery, then, would respond to a click on an Objective by reading the `objectiveId` data value of the clicked `<div>` using `.data( "objectiveId" )` (or you could store the id in the `<a>` tag of the Package link), then `show`ing the corresponding Package `<div>` below, which has an id of `<objectiveId>`. Your Package divs have already been pre-populated with data, so there's no need to keep making database calls to retrieve the data when an Objective is clicked.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! As you posted this answer, i updated my 'question'. just FYI :)

Comment: Sure. But it's best not to retrieve your related records via javascript, particularly since you only have a very small amount of data (27 items). Have your controller pass the Objectives model, along with the related packages, to the view. Then loop over the model as you did in your first code example, but remove the `()` or else you will not correctly access the related packages. The packages `<div>`s should be set to `hide` to start, and then just toggle `hide`/`show` when `onClick` is fired.

Comment: (I edited my answer to include the code to retrieve all Objectives and their related Packages.)

Comment: again thanks. The first thing is what i want yes, but the second part (the related packages show up in the objective) should not happen. 

I want to show a row with the 9 available objectives, and beneath that, have a row where the related packages will show up.

In order to get the related packages, i have to do a foreach inside the foreach objectives. Which will result in the thing i do not want..

Comment: OK, then just separate your loops; loop over the objectives in one part of your layout, and then loop over all the objectives + packages beneath that. Then use jQuery to show the corresponding packages when an objective is clicked. See edited answer.